# Me > Chrome VPN Extension > TOR > PIA VPN

Tags: vpn, google-chrome-extensions, tor

Can you please help me figure this out?

I have Linux machine with PIA VPN on it.
I also set up TOR Service with Privoxy.

And I use Chrome with Zenmate VPN extension TURNED ON.

With this setup, when I check my IP on whatismyip.com, it shows Zenmate's IP.

Then, if I TURN OFF Zenmate extension, it shows that I'm using TOR.

QUESTION: Is TOR working behind Zenmate extension (Chrome VPN > TOR > PIA VPN) ? Or does Zenmate extension prevents TOR from working properly (Chrome VPN > PIA VPN) ? How can I know this for sure?

There is very little info on using Chrome VPN extensions with TOR, and I just can't understand how such configuration works. I really hope you will be able to explain it to me. 
Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

The extension will not hide your system IP it is only to cover the browser activity. If you setup VPN connection on your machine you will be assigned IP that will hide your real IP for all activity on your PC.

As example if you setup VPN on your PC then enable ZenMate extension in your browser and go to check your IP address it will show you ZenMate IP indeed. The browser is launched on your system configuration then if you activate an extension additionally it will cover it but that may result in internet speed outage.

If you want to see real details of your system activity information [click here](https://ipleak.net/)

Comment: Hi, JoKeR! Appreciate your help. But you did not mention my Tor/Privoxy setup, and that's what I'd really want to understand.

Comment: As stated in post if you setup TOR/Privoxy in your system on that configuration your system will work and preferably hide all your system activity but does it work? For that click on the link I posted.

Comment: Is Tor service working in my setup? I mean, when I use Zenmate, do Zenmate sees that I came from Tor IP or from my machine VPN IP? When I turn WEBrtc protection off, ipleak.net shows my PIA VPN address. I want Tor to be between My VPN and Zenmate VPN extension. Hope I don't bother you too much!)

Comment: If you activate ZenMate you will see zenmate ip always because that covers browser activity if you turn off zenmate you will see the IP that is configured by your system ISP or VPN. Basically what you need is to configure a VPN on your system that will hide all of your activity. There's no need to use VPN in system and VPN extension in a browser that will only reduce your internet speed.

Comment: Thanx, man! So to be absolutely clear, TOR is working, right? And it's ok that if I turn WebRTC protection off, ipleak.net shows my PIA VPN IP?

Comment: Yes it all works in chain. The matter of security is up to you but it is recommended to have WebRTC protection on.

Comment: Sure I have WebRTC ON, and just turned it OFF for testing purposes. If it all works as I planned (Me > PIA VPN > TOR > Zenmate VPN extension > Internet), than I think Zenmate adds an additional protection. Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome. But don't forget using multiple vpn routes may result in internet speed loss.